# How to Place Text Widget at the Bottom of Flutter Page?

Tags: flutter

I have an application like this:

[image]

I want to place a `Text` widget at the bottom of the page. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:teen_browser/pages/LoginAndRegister/LoginPage.dart';
import 'package:teen_browser/pages/LoginAndRegister/RegisterPage.dart';
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 25, 25),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Image.asset("assets/Logo.png", height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Text("Ad:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                  hintText: "Ad",
                  fillColor: Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Text("Soyad:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                  hintText: "Soyad",
                  fillColor: Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Text("E-Posta:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                  hintText: "E-Posta",
                  fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Text("Parola:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                  prefixIconColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 162, 162),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                  prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
                  hintText: "Parola",
                  fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 47, 47),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16), // <-- Radius
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text("Hesap Oluştur", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Montserrat")),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried with code like this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Text("Test"),
),
```

But this code didn't work. He settled into the regular `Column` row. It's not at the bottom of the page.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Should it be always fixed at bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using another column with `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` works, also you can replace `MediaQuery` size with `LayoutBuilder.

```dart
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 25, 25),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/Logo.png",
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text("Ad:",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                            hintText: "Ad",
                            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text("Soyad:",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                            hintText: "Soyad",
                            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text("E-Posta:",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                            hintText: "E-Posta",
                            fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text("Parola:",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                            prefixIconColor:
                                const Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 162, 162),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                            prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
                            hintText: "Parola",
                            fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(179, 55, 55, 55)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16), // <-- Radius
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: const Text("Hesap Oluştur",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Montserrat")),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text("dsadas"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand you. Have you got example code?

Comment: Try update snippet

Comment: You misunderstood me. My screen turned into this: https://imgur.com/a/ATQwyoO. My purpose is this: The button will stay in the same place, other than that, a `Text` will be placed at the bottom of the page. That's what I meant.

Comment: I replaced the button and fixed the problem by putting `Text` where you put the button. Thank you.